# Two Site (Main and Mobile) and want to use same database in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have create two WordPress website , first one is main website and other one is mobile and i want to use main website database with same post table for mobile website.I have facing problem in WP Options .

Please help me out .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have 2 installs sharing the same database as long as the same plugins and themes are installed on both, you can work on edits/changes to the theme/plugin files on one site without affecting them on the other site.

Un your mobile site you need to add

```
define('WP_HOME','http://m.mysite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://m.mysite.com');
```

You would also have to worry about many few such as links inserted into your posts, which would be inserted based on the site being used to create or edit the post.

If the only reason you're doing this is to have 2 different themes one for desktop and another for mobile), i'll suggest using thid plugin **[UserAgent Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-agent-theme-switcher/)**.